# SciPy fitting gives an error

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I am fitting my function with experimental data. The function is complicated enough that I am unable to post here, but my fitting module looks like this:

```
out_put = scipy.optimize.leastsq(func, initial parameter, full_output=True, ftol=0.001, xtol=0.001, gtol = 0.001)
fitter_sol = out_put[0]
error = np.sqrt(out_put[1].diagonal())
```

The last line of code gives an error under execution, and the error looks like:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'diagonal'

What could be the potential source of this error?

Comment: I believe you've inspected the contents of `out_put` already?

Comment: Try "print(len(out_put))" and see if it has at least two elements.

Comment: Can't you reduce it down to a self-contained example that still exhibits the error (and add it to the question)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say the second result of `leastsq` is:

> None if a singular matrix encountered (indicates very flat curvature in some direction).

So your input is a singular matrix.